spring boot testcontainers "row was updated or deleted by another transaction"
I want to make an entity testing with with PostgreSQL testcontainers in my SPring boot 3.x app. First I try to insert some constraint violation records and then some valid records and then I want to delete all records, to continue testing.
In delete all records I get an error like this:
"row was updated or deleted by another transaction".
AFAIK JPA tests run under transaction. Unfortunately the database is not in my scope, that's why I cannot use @Version in the entity.
Thats my Entity:
@Entity
@Table(name= "E", schema = Const.SCHEME_NAME)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class E {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long id;

    @NotNull(message = "{name.not-blank}")
    @Column(name="name", length = 150, nullable = false)
    private String name;

my repository is a simple JpaRepository:
@Repository
public interface ERepository extends JpaRepository<E, Long> {
}

my test is:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Testcontainers
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ETestApplication.TestContainersInitializer.class)
public class ETestApplication {

 static class TestContainersInitializer implements
            ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {


    public static List<E> VALID=List.of(E.builder()
                            .name("asd")
                            .build()
    );
                  
    public static List<E> INVALID=List.of(E.builder()
                            .build()
    );

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            TestPropertyValues.of(
                            "spring.datasource.url="+ postgresService.getJdbcUrl(),
                            "spring.datasource.username="+ postgresService.getUsername(),
                            "spring.datasource.password="+ postgresService.getPassword())
                    .applyTo(applicationContext.getEnvironment());
    }
    
    @Container
    private static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresService = new 
    PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:16-alpine")
            .withInitScript("sql/init.sql");

    @LocalServerPort
    protected int port;
    @Autowired
    protected ERepository repository;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeAll() {
        try {
            postgresService.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void afterAll() {
        postgresService.stop();
    }

    protected void entityInsert(E e) {
        E saved = repository.save(e);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(saved);
        E restored = repository.findById(saved.getId())
                .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(restored);
        Assertions.assertEquals(saved, restored);
    }

    protected void entityUpdate(E e) {
        E updated = repository.save(e);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(updated);
        Assertions.assertEquals(e.entity, updated);
    }

    protected void entityDelete(E e) {
        repository.delete(e);
        repository.findById(e.getId())
                .ifPresent(d -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException("%s is not deleted".formatted(d));
                });
    }
    
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void agentServiceTest() {
              
        INVALID.forEach(e -> {
            Assertions.assertThrows(e.expectedException, () ->
                            repository.save(e.entity),
                    "constraints violated but no exception");
        });

        VALID.forEach(e -> {
            entityInsert(e);
            e.setName("bsd");
            entityUpdate(e);
            entityDelete(e.entity);
        });

        repository.deleteAll();  // Exception:  Row was updated or deleted by another transaction 
        // continue testing...
    }


}

